# With this /etc/network/interfaces configuration file attempting to create a static IP, my pi connects at two local addresses

Tags: networking, wifi

The file is as such:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.xxx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The pi is connecting to the network via the wlan connection, using a usb wifi adapter.

The pi is connected at the supplied static address and the previously assigned dhcp address. I've confirmed this via the router config page and via `ping`.

How can I correct this, and/or does it not matter?

`ip addr` returns the following under wlan0:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
link/ether zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.xx2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.1.xx1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

z replacing the hw addr

Comment: Edit in the output from `ip link`.

Comment: 3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: 'x' here standing in for hw addr

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ip addr` -- and edit it into your question, not comments.

Comment: If plausible, try rebooting your router, then the pi.

Comment: problem persists after a reboot of the router and pi. Oddly, the dhcp table did not show what was the dhcp-assigned address, `xx1` from above, until I tried pinging it, successfully.

Comment: Don't ac routers connect to two IP addressees to double the speed? Just asking.

Comment: @PaulF8080, that behavior is possible tho i've never seen such behavior on another device. why would the pi do that?

Answer (score 1):

the other IP should be from `/etc/init.d/dhcpcd`. Try this and then reboot:

```
update-rc.d dhcpcd disable
```

Comment: This command will operate on a sysV `init` system (I can't say that it wil solve the OP's question) but is it applicable to `systemd` that the current Raspbian {and most other Linux distributions have now switched to, either, by default in Debian (and thus Raspian) or compulsorily on some others}?

Comment: Both `/etc/rc3.d/S01dhcpcd` and systemd service `dhcpcd.service` are enabled in current (Nov 2015) raspbian.  However, only `/etc/rc3.d/S01dhcpcd` is launched successfully on system startup, i.e. `dhcpcd.service` is failed to run anyway.

Comment: so coming back to this after a few months, I changed the static IP and the problem has gone away for now. Will monitor.